# Is it necessary to ban malicious IP regardless of default firewall setting being deny/reject?

Tags: security, firewall, performance, fail2ban, performance-tuning

I'm on Linux and using fail2ban as the ban system. So far, it has collected and banned about 150K of malicious IPs, and I'm concerned and wondering if this will gobble a fair amount of resources. As I see it on `top`, it has a relatively high CPU time.. My questions are,

1. If there are more banned IP addresses, then will my CPU take more resources to filter an incoming connection? (My concern roots in the unverified-idea if the CPU has to compare any incoming IP with 150k-ban-list to determine filtration.)
2. If I just simply set the default firewall setting to deny/reject, then would banning the system be not necessary anymore? Or should I have the ban system running regardless? (if so, what are the reasons?)

Comment: It depends a bit on how those IP addresses are banned. Sequential checking of individual netfilter rules is more “expensive” than using an  `ipset`  to store the IP addresses but even the penalties of the first  are usually not too severe

Answer (score 0):

1. if you use some of "plain" `iptables` banning actions in fail2ban you could switch to [iptables-ipset](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/action.d/iptables-ipset.conf) or to [nftables](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/master/config/action.d/nftables.conf) action, for example:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-ipset[type=multiport]
banaction_allports = iptables-ipset[type=allports]
```

- or to [iptables-ipset-proto6](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/config/action.d/iptables-ipset-proto6.conf) and [iptables-ipset-proto6-allports](https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/blob/0.11/config/action.d/iptables-ipset-proto6-allports.conf) for older versions:

```
[DEFAULT]
banaction = iptables-ipset-proto6
banaction_allports = iptables-ipset-proto6-allports
```

2. as regards the question "deny/reject"...

   Although I must admit I don't quite understand the sentence "then would banning the system be not necessary anymore" or rather how some default firewall settings could prevent against that. If the listener ports are still open and public available.

   Any kind of banning system is not necessary if you'd either trust in strong password policies or use asymmetric keys instead of passwords by authentication (so that a bruteforce would not really make sense anymore) and certain load by continuous serving of failed authentication attempts as well as flood in log journals is acceptable for you. Or if you'd switch to some strict firewall rules whitelisting certain addresses only or open listener ports on demand only (port-, http- or whatever else knocking mechanisms), so your services become not public accessible anymore.

As for "drop vs. reject" see https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/issues/2217#issuecomment-423248516 discussion.